# Regex for entire words

Tags: java, regex, string

I need some help creating a regex. The `String` value is:

```
{"meta":[{"this_id":"111111"},{"this_id":"222222"},{"this_id":"333333"}],"type":"Account"}
```

I want to create a list with all the ids, so `element[0]` would be 111111, `element[1]` would be 222222, for example. I would also like to at least be able to isolate the type and set that to a String.

Can I receive some help on this? I tried to do

```
String[] tokens = stringToBreakUp.split(":");
```

Then I was just focused on all the tokens after the 2nd element in that list. I am not sure how to search list based on a key. I think I need some sort of key. But I am new at doing these things.

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse Json.

Comment: It Looks like JSON. Why you do not use a JSON parser?

Comment: This is not JSON actually. This is part of assignment. Sorry for confusion. This is high school assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `\\d+` to get all the numbers. Check [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wJ9xO8/1)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
while (m.find()) {
    // print m.group() to get all ids
}
```

Comment: @TheLostMind You took the easy way out now ;-)

Comment: @laune - The easier the better :P.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, actually. Our lesson is on string tokenizers, patterns and substrings. We have not learned anything about JSON, even if that was the example style/format the assignment was in. This works, thank you TheLostMind!

Comment: Ah, but you @portfoliobuilder should learn early on not to write code based on an example. If the spec says the values are all digits, OK. But otherwise: take care!

Comment: @laune You are right. But he gave us like 20 of these, all different types. I am getting good practice and learning either way. This was just one of the ones I was stuck on. But now I know a new trick using this pattern and matcher together, in combination with what I know about regex. I am completing my assignment, and I appreciate everyone's answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use any JSON parsing library such as [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and convert it into Java Object.

Sample code using `GSON` library:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);

// just iterate the map and get the desired value
```

Sample code using `Jackson` library:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("meta");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("this_id"));
}
```

output:

```
111111
222222
333333
```

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree that the RegEx is not an appropriate tool to parse JSON, but this simple test will help you to do it.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String str = "{\"meta\":[{\"this_id\":\"111111\"},{\"this_id\":\"222222\"},{\"this_id\":\"333333\"}],\"type\":\"Account\"}";

        Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\"this_id\"\\s*\\:\\s*\"(\\d+)\"\\}");
        Matcher idMatcher = idPattern.matcher(str);
        Collection<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        while (idMatcher.find()) {
            ids.add(idMatcher.group(1));
        }
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("111111", "222222", "333333"), ids);

        Pattern typePattern = Pattern.compile("\"type\"\\s*\\:\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"");
        Matcher typeMatcher = typePattern.matcher(str);
        String type = typeMatcher.find() ? typeMatcher.group(1) : null;
        assertEquals("Account", type);
    }

}
```